# Facebook graph api response taking time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My app is using the Facebook Graph API to retrieve the complete list of a Facebook user's friends:

GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends?limit=5000&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Results are taking a long time to show up. What could be the error? Is there an alternate way to fetch the results at a faster pace?

thanks.

Comment: "What could be the error?" - Get faster friends?

Comment: you should hide specific data..such as user id on public forum